# Reagarding the titanium framework

Tags: ios, titanium-mobile

I recently started trying to develop apps using titanium.
When i ran one basic app containing two table views and some static data, it showed me 80 memory leaks and about 15 warnings - i think coming from the frameworks.
As an iOS developer, i'm used to seeing less than 5 memory leaks in complex apps too.
So, I'd like to know whether applications are getting accepted by apple when developed through titanium.
Also, I'd like to know whether,looking at the state of the titanium frameworks,its worth learning it right now.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your second question is too subjective:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128562/181292

Answer (score 1):

Your First Question, Yes! they are being accepted by Apple App Store.
And For your second question, its relative to likings of individual. I started mobile application development with titanium, but soon I realized that there is no better way to create an application then to create it natively. I would say if the applications you are developing are not scaled at enterprise level magnitude (means thousands of lines of code), better develop apps natively.

Titanium is increasing support and improving frameworks rapidly, its also reduces lines of code by third! and the best thing about it is, its cross-platform! but to my personal liking i always prefer native development. The power, the iOS gives you, Titanium wont!

One more thing i would like to add, despite all, you should learn it! :)